# How to iterate array using ngFor loop in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, iteration, ngfor

```
'arr: { a: string[];b: string[];c: {id: number; name: string; }[]; } '

'''arr= {
a: ['rose', 'kelly', '35'],
b: ['marry', 'hadden', '40'],
c:[
{ id: 1, name: "Mark" },
{ id: 2, name: "John" },
{ id: 3, name: "Franc" },
{ id: 4, name: "Andrew " }
]
}
```

How to iterate above array using *ngFor loop in Angular'''

Comment: What is the issue you are facing about ngFor? What you are expecting from arr object

Comment: 'Whenever trying to iterate array on page like <h4 *ngFor="let arrList  of arr"> . getting following error message : error TS2322: Type '{ a: string[]; b: string[]; c: { id: number; name: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'.'

Answer (score 0):

`*ngFor` directive expects the `Array` object to loop over. That's why you're receiving an error.

You can use `keyvalue` pair pipe to loop over this object, basically that will convert an object to an array, which would have `key` and `value` in separate object properties.

Since strictTemplate checking, typescript is throwing an error. To fix/suppress that error you can use define type of `arr: {[key: string]: any}`.

**TS**

```
arr: {[key: string]: any} = {
  a: ...,
  b: ...,
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of arr | keyvalue">
  <b>{{ item.key }}</b>

  <div *ngFor="let val of item.value">
    {{ val.name ?? val }}
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqb5mf)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working properly. I am getting only value of a: & b: but c: only return object:object

Comment: did you use the exact HTML as I added in answer? `{{ val.name ?? val }}`

Comment: '''Yes. <div *ngFor="let item of arr | keyvalue">
    <b>{{ item.key }}:{{item.value}}</b>
    <div *ngFor="let val of item.value">
        {{val.name ?? val}}
    </div> '''

Comment: output like : c:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @Atul how `c` property looks like `c:[{ id: 1, name: "Mark" }, ... ]`

Comment: Yes, it's correct but while iterating it its only showing  c:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: after updating the code its showing error message Type 'string[] | { id: number; name: string; }[]' is not assignable to type '(string[] & NgIterable<string>) | null | undefined'.ngtsc(2322)

Comment: Check updated answer